# Can I use the Plan Cache in SQL Server Tuning Advisor when using a second server to do the workload?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, database-tuning-advisor

I work with a live production server with several hundred tables and stored procedures. Ideally, I'd use the Plan Cache option in Tuning Advisor to assist in optimizing, because jobs are run on schedules ranging from seconds to weeks apart, so profile traces won't reflect the whole system. We want to use the backup/test server to do the workload analysis, but it seems to only accept trace files or SQL scripts to analyze, which are passed as part of an XML file. Is there any way to utilize the Plan cache on the production server?

Comment: In most cases, a statement that has not run for weeks is not going to have its plan still sitting around in the cache on an highly utilized system, so the plan cache is typically less useful than a trace. If you care about optimizing the less frequent statements, the plan cache isn't likely to capture those at all; a better bet would be traces made around the time you know the jobs run. If you really want to capture the full load, set up mirroring/high availability so your backup server sees the same load, then trace/optimize on that.

Comment: Thank you, Jeroen. We are unable to set up mirroring because it is a large client company, whose server is running one of our products. I understand about the Plan Cache not being useful for the rarer jobs, so may have to optimize them separately. However, as there are up to 50K transactions a minute, the general running over the period of a week would still be better handled by the Plan Cache? If so, would we have to do the workload analysis on Live?